# Is scalar multiplication unique in a normed space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a vector space over the  field $K=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$  with  norm $\|\cdot\|$, and suppose $\cdot,*:K\times X\to X$ are two scalar products making $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ a normed space. Can we say that  $\alpha \cdot x=\alpha* x$ for all $\alpha\in K$ and $x\in X$?

It seems to me that following argument shows the answer to be yes if $\alpha \in \mathbb R$:

First we have $1\cdot x=1*x=x$ by definition since $1$ is the multiplicative identity. By induction and using distributivity of scalar multiplication over vector addition we obtain $n\cdot x=n*x$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Since $-1\cdot x=-1*x=-x$ we obtain $-n\cdot x=(-1)\cdot(n \cdot x)=-1*(n\cdot x)=-1*(n*x)=-n*x$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Also $0\cdot x=0*x=0$, so we have $n \cdot x=n*x$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. Next if $n\in \mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ then $\frac{1}{n} \cdot x=\frac{1}{n}\cdot (1*x)= \frac{1}{n} \cdot (n* \frac{1}{n}*x)=\frac{1}{n} \cdot ( n \cdot \frac{1}{n}*x)=1 \cdot (\frac{1}{n}*x)=\frac{1}{n}*x$ and so another induction shows that  $q\cdot x=q*x$ for all $q\in\mathbb Q$.

Finally suppose $\alpha=\mathbb R$ and choose any sequence $(\alpha_n) \subset \mathbb Q$ converging to $\alpha$. Then

$$\|\alpha \cdot x-\alpha*x\|\leq \|\alpha \cdot x-\alpha_n \cdot x\|+\|\alpha_n*x-\alpha* x\|= |\alpha-\alpha_n|\|x\| +|\alpha_n-\alpha|\|x\|\to 0$$

as $n\to \infty$ . Therefore $\|\alpha \cdot x-\alpha*x\|=0$ which implies $\alpha \cdot x=\alpha*x$.

For the case $\alpha \in \mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$ I don't think we can say anything. For example consider the scalar product definition  $\alpha * x:=\bar{\alpha} \cdot x$ for all $x\in X$ and $\alpha\in K$. Then this scalar product makes $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ a normed space but for $\alpha \in \mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$ and and $x\neq 0$ we have $\alpha \cdot x\neq \alpha *x$.

Am I missing something? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The complex scalar multiplication you mention in the dual of a Hilbert space can be used to make the Riesz representaion an isomorphism.

Comment: What about $\alpha * x := - \alpha \cdot x$? You need to assume that the multiplicative identity is the same

Comment: @daw But in this case $1 * x := - 1 \cdot x=-x\neq x$ unless $x=0$. This is not compatible with the property of scalar multiplication on a vector space.

Comment: I though for a while that your example $\alpha\ast x=\overline\alpha \cdot x$ might be the only one. This however is not true. On $\mathbb C^2$ another example is $\alpha\ast (z_1,z_2)=(\alpha\cdot z_1,\overline\alpha \cdot z_2)$.

Comment: @Jochen Yes that works too if you give $\mathbb C^2$ the usual euclidean norm. Do you think the rest of my reasoning is correct?

Comment: Yes, your arguments are fine.